# Split string with repeated delimiters

Tags: r, regex, string, strsplit

I have a string in R in the following form:

```
example <- c("namei1 namej1, surname1, name2, surnamei2 surnamej2, name3, surname3")
```

And I wish to obtain two columns:

```
namei1 namej1   | surname1
name2           | surnamei2 surnamej2
name3           | surname3
```

I try using string split:

```
example <- c("namei1 namej1, surname1, name2, surnamei2 surnamej2, name3, surname3")
pattern <- "\\,+[[:space:]]"
str_split(example, pattern)
```

But, I get stuck from here…

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
read.csv(text = gsub("([^,]+,[^,]+),", "\\1\n", example), 
         header = FALSE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

```
#              V1                   V2
# 1 namei1 namej1             surname1
# 2         name2  surnamei2 surnamej2
# 3         name3             surname3
```

Comment: Could you explain the regex?

Comment: @camille it looks for commas in pair and replaces the second one (`\\1` keeps the first one) with `\n` which is `newline`. `read.csv` uses comma as column-delimiter and `\n` will be interpreted as new row. I could've used `(,[^,]*),` as well.

Answer (score 4):

We can split the string at `,` followed by zero or more spaces (`\\s*`), then create a grouping variable based on the occurance of 'name' string and `split` the `vector` (`v1`) into a `list` of `vector`s, `rbind the`list`elements and convert it to a`data.frame`

```
v1 <- strsplit(example, ",\\s*")[[1]]
setNames(do.call(rbind.data.frame, split(v1, cumsum(grepl('\\bname',
       v1)))), paste0("V", 1:2))
#       V1                  V2
#1 namei1 namej1            surname1
#2         name2 surnamei2 surnamej2
#3         name3            surname3
```

---

Or another option is `scan` and convert it to a two column `matrix`

```
as.data.frame( matrix(trimws(scan(text = example, sep=",",
      what = "", quiet = TRUE)), byrow = TRUE, ncol = 2))
#       V1                  V2
#1 namei1 namej1            surname1
#2         name2 surnamei2 surnamej2
#3         name3            surname3
```

---

Or another option is `gsub` where we replace the `,` followed by space and 'name' string with `\n` and 'name' and use that in. `read.csv` to split based on the delimiter `,`

```
read.csv(text = gsub(", name", "\nname", example), header= FALSE)
#         V1                   V2
#1 namei1 namej1             surname1
#2         name2  surnamei2 surnamej2
#3         name3             surname3
```

Comment: What happens if you skip `trimws`?

Comment: @M- issue is that `scan` `sep` takes a single character.  I could include `strip.white = TRUE` and avoid the `trimws` though `scan(text = example, sep=",",
       what = "", quiet = TRUE, strip.white = TRUE)`. I thought if i use `trimws`, it can be made more compact.  Nothing else

Answer (score 3):

```
data.frame(split(unlist(strsplit(example, ", ")), c(0, 1)))
#             X0                  X1
#1 namei1 namej1            surname1
#2         name2 surnamei2 surnamej2
#3         name3            surname3
```